# Что делать после изучения основ?

Tags: c#

У меня такая проблема. Я самостоятельно изучаю c#, для создания игр. Так вот, я изучил основы языка и не знаю, что дальше делать. Хочется уже сделать свою игру, а с чего начать, я не знаю. Когда я начинаю решать какие то задачи, то вообще не понимаю. Например задача, сделать функцию которое при вводе строки делала некоторые буквы большими. Или функцию которое делает текст ревирсивным(незнаю как назвать), например, ввёл asdg, а возвращать должно, gdsa. Ну я создаю функцию, что-то туда добавляю, и все, я не знаю, что делать дальше. И когда пытаюсь написать например змейку, тоже самое.  Что в таком случае делать. Когда изучаю что-то новое в языке, то все понимаю. Я нашел в интернете, что нужно разбить задачу на подзачачи. Ну я разбиваю задачу, а когда дело доходит до кода, то все. Незнаю как сделать букву большой, или переместить букву в конец, или начало.

Comment: Возьмите хороший набор курсов и смотрите. Думаю где скачать найдете. Что за курсы - можете посмотреть на YouTube, а потом найти их на просторах интернета. Посмотрите часов 150-200 курсов и на первую работу, а там разберетесь.

Comment: Если бы вопрос был об играх, то я бы написал -- *`Игру надо начинать с идеи, которая воплощается сначала в сценарии (на естественном языке, с эскизами сцен). А уже потом вы выбираете подходящий язык программирования (может быть и не один) и пишете реализацию.`*. А пока, задавайте конкретные вопросы, типа "как сделать букву большой" и "как реверсировать строку"...

Comment: Посмотрите вот этот [канал](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCVlKtIaegCXNkutzMJ5Rfhg). Парень делает много разных небольших проектов игр. Смотрите и делайте за ним, так вы "набъёте " руку и сможете кодить самостоятельно. Только не занимайтесь самообманом, просто смотреть видео как кинцо абсолютно бесполезное занятие. Надо именно писать за автором, пытаясь понять, что делается, для чего делается, как делается.